# Pro strategies for Kirby in Super Smash Bros. (N64)

Tags: super-smash-bros

What are some of the more exploited moves, combo sequences and tips and tricks pros use for playing Kirby in Super Smash Bros for Nintendo 64?

I feel Kirby has a weakness against Fox, but that may be just me, but if relevant counter-strategies for that (or against any other 'difficult' opponent for Kirby) are also appreciated.

Comment: Note that kirby is a top character in that game.

Comment: Two words: up-tilt.  Fox is a top character as well but the main weakness Kirby has against Fox is being too slow to chase him down.

Comment: Yep, up tilt and dair. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D52KGq4jlMQ

Answer (score 7):

Not to brag, but I was notoriously good with Kirby. My friends hated me :P Its been a while since I've played, so forgive me if I don't know exact key mappings.

Kirby's strength is not from his power moves (the B+direction ones) but from simple aerial attacks and smash attacks (the A+direction ones). The "drill" attack is your main weapon. Float around the map until you find a target you can drill into the ground. If your opponent sees you circling them, they'll counter the drill attack with a power move. Anticipate whether they're prepared or not, and if they are prepared try your B+up move.

After you drill someone into the ground, they'll bounce up for a few seconds. This is a great opportunity to use your A+up. This will knock weak enemies completely off the map. If not, they'll still be vulnerable in the air. You could just jump up and A+right them for a painful 2-smash combo, which will surely send them flying far away from you. Or you could try B+upping them or drilling them again.

Answer (score 4):

While in the air, you can down-A (which is a spinning kick), then smash them when they are recovering then jump off the ledge after them and finish with a down-A. Kirby's down-A is usually an instant kill when above the abyss